# MySQL return rows where column contains categories defined by array (and add weight to the results)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, categories

In my app, the user can type in an indefinite amount of categories to search by. Once the user hits submit, I am using AJAX to call my PHP script to query my DB and return the results that match what the user defined for the categories.

My category column is separated as so for each row: "blue,red,yellow,green" etc.

I have two questions:

1. How can I pass an array to MySQL (like so: [blue,yellow,green]) and then search for each term in the categories column? If at-least one category is found, it should return that row.
2. Can MySQL add weight to a row that has more of the categories that the user typed in, therefor putting it further to the top of the returned results? If MySQL cannot do this, what would be the best way to do this with PHP?

Thanks for taking the time and looking at my issue.

Comment: I'm kind of a master of MySQL lol, let me know if my answer helped

Answer (score 0):

For the part 1 you can use the function below:

```
<?php
function createquery($dataarray){
    $query="select * from table where ";
    $loop=1;
    foreach($dataarray as $data)
    {
      $query.="col='$data'";
      if(count($dataarray)<$loop-1){
        $query.=' or ';
      }
      $loop++;
    }
    return $query;
}

?>
```

This will return the long query.

Answer (score 0):

use this some like this:

```
mysql_query("select * from table where category in (".implode($yourarray,',').")");
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

Arrays are not passed to a MySQL database. What's past is a query which is a string that tells the database what action you want to preform. An example would be: `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 1`.

Since you are trying to use the values inside your array to search in the database, you could preform a `foreach` loop to create a valid SQL **command** with all those columns in PHP, and then send that **command / query** to the database. For example:

```
$array = array('blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green');

$sql = "SELECT ";
foreach ($array as $value)
{
  $sql .= $value.", ";
}
$sql .= " FROM myTable WHERE id = 1";
```

**IMPORTANT! It is highly recommended to used prepared statements and binding your parameters in order not to get hacked with sql injection!**

**2)**

You are able to order the results you obtained in whichever way you like. An example of ordering your results would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE SALARY > 2000 ORDER BY column1, column2 DESC
```